# Excel VBA, Checking for value from a cell in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that needs to check if there is a 1 in a cell from the same row. The problem I have is that I need to do that for a range of 3 columns.

Actually, this part doesn't work at all but I can put it in cells form.

I need to check for all the cells from ("P3:R" & iNbKids) if there is a 1 in the cell ("K" & ActiveCell.Row). I have tried a lot of things but I can't seem to figure it out.

iNbKids is an Integer

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the code or a screenshot?

Comment: As I said, nothing is working right now for that part, but I can add what I have. I need to have the cells in r2 yellow only if there is a 1 in one or more cells in the range (k:activecell.row).  

That's where my problem is.  

Set r2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("p3 : r" & iNbEnfants + 2)   

'For Each Cell In r2  
If Cell.Value <> 0 Then  
Cell.Select  
With ActiveCell.Interior  
.Pattern = xlSolid  
.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic  
.Color = 65535  
.TintAndShade = 0  
.PatternTintAndShade = 0  
End With  
End If  
Next

Comment: I have no clue how to format, I'm sorry

Comment: you need to put it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure, but it looks like you need to change

```
If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
```

To

```
If Range("K"&r2.row).Value <> 0 Then
```

Or

```
If Range("K"&r2.row).Value = 1  Then
```